# swift 2 character limit in a label ( string )

Tags: string, swift2, character

I have a converter app.

[converter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5jMv.png)

I want the label to only go up to a 5 character limit based on a string.
This is the code I have so far.( var calculateArea is the string linked to the UILabel ). Any help will be appreciated.

```
@IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!
var calculateArea: String!
let maxDigits:Int = 5



func StringLimit() -> String {
    calculateArea.characters.count <= maxDigits

    return calculateArea
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see if that helps you

```
func StringLimit(str:String, remove:Int)->String
{
    var result = str
    let range = result.index(result.endIndex, offsetBy: -remove)..<result.endIndex
    result.removeSubrange(range)

    return result
}

print(StringLimit(str:"today",remove:2)) //tod
```

Comment: I get an error by let range = result.index. I'm using xcode 7.2

Comment: Are you using swift 3?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.Run the code in https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl

Comment: I'm using Swift2.2, I'll have to try it on another mac to find out. Thanks.